# How to make TextView maximum number of lines - if more - scrolable

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have recyclerView, each itemView contain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

        <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100sp">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/answer"/>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

By using this kotlin file I made TextViews to be scrollable inside of RecyclerView (textView are scrolable only if they do not fit to 100sp).

```
            itemView.answer.setOnTouchListener{v,event ->
            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
            v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
            false
        }
```

Same file in java format:

```
            itemView.answer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The problem is that, then TextView contains 1 or 2 lines of text only, there are a lot of empty space inside of that TextView. I want to do something like this: when there are 1-5 line of text inside of TextView its height is just "wrap_content"
and it is not scrollable.
But when there are 6 of more lines of text, it fits 5 lines only, to see other lines user needs to scroll that TextView.

How can I do this?
Screenshot of current RecyclerView:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should never include scrolling views inside of your `ViewHolder`s. It will lead to unpredictable behavior and end users will be frustrated when they'll try to scroll the list and they end up scrolling contents of your `ViewHolder`. A match better way would be implementing expandable `ViewHolder`s which at collapsed state would show e.g. 3 lines of text, and all of them in the expanded state.